# Split a column in spark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a torque column with 2500 rows in spark data frame with data like

```
torque
190Nm@ 2000rpm
250Nm@ 1500-2500rpm
12.7@ 2,700(kgm@ rpm)
22.4 kgm at 1750-2750rpm
11.5@ 4,500(kgm@ rpm)
```

I want to split each row in two columns Nm and rpm like

```
Nm        | rpm
190Nm     |  2000rpm
250Nm     | 1500-2500rpm
12.7Nm    | 2,700(kgm@ rpm)
22.4 kgm  | 1750-2750rpm
11.5Nm    | 4,500(kgm@ rpm)
```

How do I do it in databricks?

I tried doing it using

```python
type herefrom pyspark.sql.functions import split, trim, regexp_extract, when
df=cars

# Assuming the name of your dataframe is "df" and the torque column is "torque"
df = df.withColumn("torque_split", split(df["torque"], "@"))

# Extract the torque values and units, assign to columns 'torque_value' and 'torque_units'
df = df.withColumn("torque_value", trim(regexp_extract(df["torque_split"].getItem(0), r'\d+\.?\d*', 0)))
df = df.withColumn("torque_units", trim(regexp_extract(df["torque_split"].getItem(0), r'[a-zA-Z]+', 0)))

# Extract the rpm values and assign to the 'rpm' column
df = df.withColumn("rpm", trim(regexp_extract(df["torque_split"].getItem(1), r'\d+-?\d*\s?rpm', 0)))

# Convert kgm values to Nm
df = df.withColumn("Nm", 
                   when(df["torque_units"] == "kgm", df["torque_value"] * 9.80665)
                   .otherwise(df["torque_value"]))

# Drop the original torque, torque_split and torque_units columns
df = df.drop("torque", "torque_split", "torque_units", "torque_value")

# Show the resulting dataframe
df.display()
```

but I am getting null values at instances when data is like 2,700(kgm@ rpm)

Comment: I would suggest you to write a python function that is capable of parsing each individual string values and then use PySpark UDF to use it in your dataframe https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Answer (score 2):

An approach without UDFs:

1. Extract the first two groups of numbers using [regexp_extract_all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all)
2. Adjust a factor for the torque value if the original string contains `kgm`
3. Split the array from step 1 into two columns and multiply the factor from step 2
4. Drop the intermediate columns

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ...

df.withColumn("numbers", F.expr("regexp_extract_all(Torque, '([0-9,.\-]+)')")) \
  .withColumn("factor", F.when(F.instr("Torque", "kgm") > 0 , 9.80665).otherwise(1.0)) \
  .withColumn("torque value", F.col("numbers")[0] * F.col("factor")) \
  .withColumn("rpm", F.col("numbers")[1]) \
  .drop("numbers", "factor") \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+------------------------+------------------+---------+
|Torque                  |torque value      |rpm      |
+------------------------+------------------+---------+
|190Nm@ 2000rpm          |190.0             |2000     |
|250Nm@ 1500-2500rpm     |250.0             |1500-2500|
|12.7@ 2,700(kgm@ rpm)   |124.54445499999999|2,700    |
|22.4 kgm at 1750-2750rpm|219.66895999999997|1750-2750|
|11.5@ 4,500(kgm@ rpm)   |112.77647499999999|4,500    |
+------------------------+------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a python function that is capable of parsing each individual string values and then use [PySpark UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/) to use it in your dataframe. For instance:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StringType

# Define UDFs for extracting RPM and torque values from the torque string column
def extract_torque_udf(torque_string):
    # Define regular expressions for matching torque values and units
    nm_regex = r"\d+(\.\d+)?\s*(kgm)?Nm"
    kgm_regex = r"\d+(\.\d+)?\s*(kgm)?"

    # Search for matches in the input string
    nm_match = re.search(nm_regex, torque_string)
    kgm_match = re.search(kgm_regex, torque_string)

    # Extract the torque value and unit from the matching regular expression
    if nm_match:
        torque_value = float(nm_match.group().replace("kgm", "").replace("Nm", ""))
    elif kgm_match:
        # convert kgm to Nm
        torque_value = float(kgm_match.group().replace("kgm", "")) * 9.80665
    else:
        raise ValueError("Torque string does not match expected format")

    return torque_value

def extract_rpm_udf(torque_string):
    # Define regular expression for matching rpm values
    rpm_regex = r"(\d+(?:,\d+)*-\d+(?:,\d+)*)\s*rpm|\b(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\s*rpm|\d+(?:,\d+)*\s*(?=\(kgm@ rpm\))"

    # Search for matches in the input string
    rpm_match = re.search(rpm_regex, torque_string)

    # Extract the rpm value(s) from the matching regular expression
    if rpm_match:
        rpm_value = rpm_match.group(1) or rpm_match.group(2) or rpm_match.group(0)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Torque string does not contain rpm values")

    return rpm_value

# Define the PySpark UDFs for the two functions
extract_torque = udf(extract_torque_udf, DoubleType())
extract_rpm = udf(extract_rpm_udf, StringType())

# Define the PySpark DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Torque Extraction").getOrCreate()

data = [("190Nm@ 2000rpm",), 
        ("250Nm@ 1500-2500rpm",),
        ("12.7@ 2,700(kgm@ rpm)",),
        ("22.4 kgm at 1750-2750rpm",),
        ("11.5@ 4,500(kgm@ rpm)",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Torque"])

# Add the RPM and torque value columns using the PySpark UDFs
df = df.withColumn("RPM", extract_rpm("Torque"))
df = df.withColumn("Torque Value", extract_torque("Torque"))

# Display the resulting DataFrame
df.show()
```

| Torque | RPM | Torque Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 190Nm@ 2000rpm | 2000 | 190.0 |
| 250Nm@ 1500-2500rpm | 1500-2500 | 250.0 |
| 12.7@ 2,700(kgm@ ... | 2,700 | 124.54445499999999 |
| 22.4 kgm at 1750-... | 1750-2750 | 219.66895999999997 |
| 11.5@ 4,500(kgm@ ... | 4,500 | 112.77647499999999 |